# permission denied while installing OPENNI on mac

Tags: openni

I got this error while installing OpenNI ON MAC

```
./install.sh
Installing OpenNI
****************************

copying shared libraries...cp: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.dylib: Permission denied
cp: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.jni.dylib: Permission denied
cp: /usr/lib/libnimCodecs.dylib: Permission denied
cp: /usr/lib/libnimMockNodes.dylib: Permission denied
cp: /usr/lib/libnimRecorder.dylib: Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

You'll be prompted for an admin password.

Comment: i've tried installing it with nite many times, but does not work,i'll  follow the instructions written in get hub /openni, again and tell u the result, very thanks